# Prioritizing objects using valued filters

Tags: python, django, postgresql, filter

I have an interesting programming question which I'm sure has many very interesting solutions and I'm hoping someone has some insight into a good direction I can take.

I'm working in Django and I have a QuerySet of objects and a set of filters. I want to find a subset of objects that survive all the filters, but this is not always possible, so I want to order the queryset so that the objects that survive the most important filters come before ones that always get filtered out. I define an importance level for each of these filters.

So, at an abstract level, given a set of objects and a set of weighted constraints, I want an ordered list of objects by the weight they achieve.

For example,
given a set of words:

```
{'Almond', 'Red', 'Apple', 'Gargle', 'Anyone'}
```

And a set of valued filters:

```
- Starts with A, worth 10 points

- Ends with E, worth 5 points

- 6 letters long, worth 3 points
```

The following array is returned, with associated point scores:

```
[['Anyone',18],['Apple',15],['Almond', 13],['Gargle',8],['Red',0]]
```

Since these are objects and filters in Django, I would also like to use as may queryset functions as possible as opposed to loops to improve runtime and complexity (I am using PostgreSQL, so any PostgreSQL-specific solutions are fine).
So basically, if I have n objects and f filters, I want to achieve a better complexity than `O(nf+nlogn)` or else at least optimize the solution for Django.

Comment: why do you think that aggregating this kind of data in postgres would be faster than aggregating it in python?(note that i have no idea if it would or would not ... but I doubt you can do anything other than an exhaustive search)

Comment: From Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/performance/
"...the database can typically do things faster than Python can". This seems to be the basis of my understanding, and I thought the annotate() and aggregate() functions in QuerySet might lend some interesting solutions, although I've had no success so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, IntegerField, Case, When, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Length

# You can register function as a transform
CharField.register_lookup(Length, 'length')

filters = [
    (Q(name__startswith='A'), 10),
    (Q(name__endswith='E'), 5),
    (Q(name__length=6), 3),
]

Item.objects.annotate(
    # sum, not Sum
    tot_score=sum(Case(When(filter, then=score),
                       default=0,
                       output_field=IntegerField())
                  for filter, score in filters)
).values_list('name', 'tot_score').order_by('-tot_score')
```

[Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!